# How to support a turn in a staircase?

Tags: stairs

This is for a shed.  I'm having problems finding enough support for either stringer and I can't find any close-up images of how this might be done.  My only choice seems to be to pull the lower staircase back from the upper.  Is there a way to make this work within this tighter space?

[image: stairs]

Comment: You can also extend the platform towards the upper flight (the upper stringer lands **on** the platform, not **under** it) and support by post (the general idea of which is similar to the existing answer.)

Answer (score 19):

[Dog-Leg stairs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog-leg_(stairs))

> Structurally, the flights of a dog-leg stair are usually supported by the half-landing, which spans the adjoining flank walls.

[image: Staircase plan]
<sup>Image: [Bill Bradley. CC by SA 3.0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog-leg_(stairs)#/media/File:Quarter-space-landings.gif)</sup>

In this arrangement, the stringers are joined to a newel post. The lower landing is also partly supported by the newel post. The upper by only the flanking walls and, I guess, effectively braced by lower stringers.

Comment: I have built this type of lower landing with four posts under the landing when it was an outdoor stairs and there were no adjoining walls. Same could be done here if the walls are very difficult to mount to. One example would be an older basement with rock walls.